# Differential Equations - Substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y=y(t)$ be the general solution to the first order non-linear differential equation: $$y'(t) = q_0(t) +q_1(t)y(t) + q_2(t) (y(t))^2$$ Use the substitution $y = -\frac{u'}{q_2 u}$ to derive a second order linear equation for $u$ of the form $$u'' - Ru' + Su = 0$$ where $R$ and $S$ are suitable functions.

I have no idea where to start here. Usually I would find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ in terms of $u$, but we have $q_2$ as a function of $t$ as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your idea would still work, just be a little messier. Try finding $\frac{dy}{dt}$ yourself and see how that goes.

Comment: @B.Mehta I have and I end up with a mess :( This was a past exam question, so I'd like to know the 'cleaner', 'quicker' way if possible please :(

Comment: I'm afraid that's the best way, especially since the question tells you to use that substitution.

Comment: @B.Mehta Is this correct for $\frac{dy}{dt} = \left(-\frac{u''}{q_2u} + \frac{u'}{q_2 (u')^2}\right)\frac{du}{dt} = \left(-\frac{u''}{q_2u} + \frac{u'}{q_2 (u')^2}\right)u' = ... $ ?

Comment: That doesn't look right to me, check it and try again and if not I'll post my working as an answer.  The problem doesn't turn out to be that bad

Comment: @B.Mehta I got that on my first attempt (before I posted) and again when I just tried it now :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59390/discussion-between-b-mehta-and-physicsmathslove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute $\require{cancel}\frac{dy}{dt}$, as we discussed in the comments.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt} \left(-\frac{u'}{q_2 u}\right) \\
&=-\frac{u''(q_2u)-u'\frac{d}{dt}(q_2u)}{(q_2u)^2} \\
&=-\frac{u''(q_2u)-u'(q_2' u + q_2 u')}{(q_2u)^2} \\
&=\frac{uu'q_2'+u'^2q_2 -u''u q_2}{(q_2u)^2} \\
\end{align}$$
Not entirely tidy, but not terrible either.  Substitute this into the original differential equation.  From here, (spoilers in case you'd like to work this out yourself)

> $$\begin{align} y'(t) &= q_0(t) +q_1(t)y(t) + q_2(t) (y(t))^2 \\ \frac{uu'q_2'+u'^2q_2 -u''u q_2}{(q_2u)^2} &= q_0-q_1\frac{u'}{q_2 u}+q_2\frac{u'^2}{(q_2u)^2} \\ uu'q_2'+\cancel{u'^2q_2} -u''u q_2 &= q_0 (q_2 u)^2-q_1 u' (q_2 u)+\cancel{q_2 u'^2} \\ 0&=uu''q_2-uu'q_1q_2-uu'q_2'+q_0q_2^2u^2 \\ 0&=u''q_2-u'q_1q_2-u'q_2'+q_0q_2^2u \end{align}$$